# JPA + JSF field column with multiple descriptions

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

For each column in my entity bean I have 2 descriptions (for 2 different languages), I want to use these descriptions in different cases from my session bean.

In case the user choose language X , I want to get the field description in the X language, and accordinally for the Y language.

My question is how can I save these 2 different descriptions for each field?

Is it possible to create an annotation that will contain the 2 different values, and according to the one I want I will be able to extract it from these annotation?

Comment: I'll point you to an JSF 2 Internationalization Example http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/

Comment: He's talking about class-level 'documentation', am I right? I am realy curious also if this is possible, good question.